# IAR Workbench - How to get the file name and its path of the code appears in dis-assembly window?

Tags: disassembly, iar

While debugging an issue with IAR workbench, I could see the current PC points in the assembly code. I need to edit the same code but I'm not able to locate the file location. This is a start-up file whihc IAR automatically includes. There are many variants of the same file name in the IAR workbench folder. So, I'd like to how to get the file name and its path of the code appears in dis-assembly window?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any easy way to find the file name of the symbols shown in the IAR dis-assembly window. But this could be done in the following (straight forward) way:

1. Open the `.map` file typically stored under `List` directory where
   IAR project is stored
2. Search for the symbol you saw in dis-assembly window and find out
   the corresponding `.o`  file
3. Use the same file name and find out where it's included (in the form
   of `.c` or `.s` )in the IAR project.
4. If it's not directly included, then it might be part of the
   pre-built library (`.a` file). In this case, you can find out the
   library (`.a`) file name in the same `.map` file. Then you need to
   dig out how the library is built? and where the sources are?